# jQuery - Change input type based on selection value

Tags: jquery, html

I need to change a input type inside a `div` based on a `select` value. Here is my HTML-

```
<div id="query_template" class="hide">
    <div class="col-md-12 query_row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select name="t_col" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Col 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 2</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 3</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 4</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 5</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select name="t_rel" class="form-control">
                    <option value="equal">=</option>
                    <option value="greater_than">></option>
                    <option value="less_than"><</option>
                    <option value="like">LIKE</option>
                    <option value="range">RANGE</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 t_val">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn row-plus btn-primary">
                        <a href="#" name="plus">+</a>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn row-minus btn-primary">
                        <a href="#" name="minus">-</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change below input type-

```
<div class="col-md-5 t_val">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
```

based on -

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select name="t_rel" class="form-control">
        <option value="equal">=</option>
        <option value="greater_than">></option>
        <option value="less_than"><</option>
        <option value="like">LIKE</option>
        <option value="range">RANGE</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As far I've written the below `jQuery` code-

```
var changeValueInput = function () {
    var $valueInput = $("select[name=t_rel]");
    $valueInput.change(function () {
        if ($valueInput.val() == 'like') {
            $(this).parent().closest("div.t_val").remove("input").append("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");
        } else if ($valueInput.val() == 'range') {
            $(this).parent().closest("div.t_val").remove("input").append("another-input-type-or-any-other-html");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().closest("div.t_val").remove("input").append("another-input-type-or-any-other-html");
        }
    });
}
```

But nothing is happening. Any support will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you didn't execute the function and also the `$(this).parent().closest("div.t_val")` is not working.

Change your jQuery code like this:

```
var changeValueInput = function () {
    var $valueInput = $("select[name=t_rel]");

    $valueInput.change(function () {
        var el = $(this).parents('.row').find(".t_val");
        if ($valueInput.val() == 'like') {
            el.find('input').remove();
            el.append("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");      
        } else if ($valueInput.val() == 'range') {
            el.find('input').remove();
            el.append("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");
        } else {
            el.find('input').remove();
            el.append("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");
        }
    });
}

changeValueInput();
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ebdg3q71/2/

---

Also you can write it like this:

```
var changeValueInput = function () {
    var $valueInput = $("select[name=t_rel]");

    $valueInput.change(function () {
        var el = $(this).parents('.row').find(".t_val");
        if ($valueInput.val() == 'like') {
            el.html('');
            el.html("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");
        } else if ($valueInput.val() == 'range') {
            el.html('');
            el.html("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");
        } else {
            el.html('');
            el.html("<input type='number' class='some-other-class'>");
        }
    });
}

changeValueInput();
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ebdg3q71/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select[name="t_rel"]').change(function(){
            var selectedVal = $(this).val();
            console.log(selectedVal);

            $('.t_val').html('').html('<input type="password" class="form-control" value="">');
        });
```

This code will change your input text into password each time when dropdown selection changed. 
Put your conditions and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("select[name=t_rel]").on("change",function(){

    $value = $(this).val();
    $input = $(".col-md-5 input");

    if($value == 'like')
        $input.removeAttr("class").attr({type:"number",class:"some-other-class"});

    else if ($value == 'range') 
        $input.removeAttr("class").attr({type:"password",class:"some-other-class"});

    else 
        $input.removeAttr("class").attr({type:"email",class:"some-other-class"}); 

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="query_template" class="hide">
    <div class="col-md-12 query_row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select name="t_col" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Col 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 2</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 3</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 4</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 5</option>
                    <option value="1">Col 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select name="t_rel" class="form-control">
                    <option value="equal">=</option>
                    <option value="greater_than">></option>
                    <option value="less_than"><</option>
                    <option value="like">LIKE</option>
                    <option value="range">RANGE</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-5 t_val">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn row-plus btn-primary">
                        <a href="#" name="plus">+</a>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn row-minus btn-primary">
                        <a href="#" name="minus">-</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("select[name=t_rel]").on("change",function(){

            $value = $(this).val();
            $input = $(".col-md-5 input");

            if($value == 'like')
                $input.removeAttr("class").attr({type:"number",class:"some-other-class"});

            else if ($value == 'range') 
                $input.removeAttr("class").attr({type:"password",class:"some-other-class"});

            else 
                $input.removeAttr("class").attr({type:"email",class:"some-other-class"}); 

        })

        })
                           

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```